# If I didn't complete the 10 million challenge can I still complete it later?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

If I didn't accomplish the 10 million challenge of GTA heists, can I still finish it the next time I do the challenge? (and still get the 10 million)

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can. In fact you will most likely have quite a few trials at it: even with a well trained team this is an extremely hard challenge. My team got it after 5 trials. When you fail, you have to restart from scratch with the Fleeca heist.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen, if you fail the requirements of the challenge, you can start it over by redoing the heists.
Here is a guy who completed the challenge. http://www.reddit.com/r/gtaonline/comments/2zteay/completed_criminal_mastermind_10mill_ask_me/